# Purpose of [sampling] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently the [sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sampling) tag refers to the signal processing usage of the word (the reduction of a continuous signal to a discrete signal).  However, the questions seem to be primarily the statistical definition - ie, selecting a smaller number of records from a larger number of records (Typically for statistical purposes and/or to survey a section of the population).

Should the tag be split (there are still some true signal-sampling questions), or simply changed to the statistical meaning, or left alone?

Comment: I don't see a clear majority of statistics questions, DSP sampling rate questions are half or more of the first page.

Answer (score 4):

If this were [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) I'd say leave it be, but as you mentioned we have a lot of questions with both meanings. The best option is to split the tag into two more meaningful ones.

Comment: Perhaps `signal-sampling` and `population-sampling` ?