# Here is an ex-[sample] of a bad tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample) (720 questions) is almost entirely questions like this one:

- [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653/1768232)

> I'm trying to find a simple example that clearly shows a single task being divided for multi-threading.
>
> Quite frankly, many of the examples are overly sophisticated thus making the flow tougher to play with.
>
> Does anyone care to share their breakthrough sample or an example?

However, [sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sampling) seems to be quite a good tag, though it possibly needs some disambiguation between audio sampling and statistical sampling. Related: [Purpose of [sampling] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255585/1768232)

Therefore, I propose:

- Close all the questions asking for a code sample in [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample)
- Burn / delete all the questions of that sort
- Retag all the ones that are talking about audio samples or statistical samples to [sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sampling)

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Redraw [sample]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299731/1768232) because that is a synonym request and this is a burninate request.

[image: Fire samples]

Comment: We don't need quite a graphic display thanks :)

Comment: How can This question (asking for sample code) has so many upvotes. Its 5 year older thats why, otherwise if this question is asked now a days, should be closed within minutes with many downvotes

Comment: Here's an easy 35 to burn: [\[sample\] + where can I get](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsample%5D+where+can+i+get)

Comment: @AeroX you mean, vtc-ing, and then delete them ;)

Comment: [sample-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample-data) also looks dubious.